# How to enable outbound connections for a Docker container?

Tags: azure, docker, asp.net-core, outbound

I have an `ASP.NET Core` application that is hosted in the `Docker cloud` (cloud provider is `Azure`). The application uses `Hangfire` to run recurring jobs in the background, and one of the jobs needs to request data from an external REST API. I noticed that any attempt at outbound communication fails, and I would like to know, how I can enable it.

The deployment consists of some other containers, whereby linked containers (services) can communicate with no problem. There is no special network configuration; the default "bridge" mode is used. Do I need to configure something in the container´s image, or do I need to make changes to the network settings... I have no clue.

Comment: if you app is accessible externally,i dont see a reason why the restapi fails(IMHO)..what is the exact error message

Comment: @TheGameiswar It´s not my own REST API that cannot be reached, connections via exposed ports work as expected. Outbound requests of the dockerized app to services on the internet do fail...

Comment: I was just stupid (-; the `Hangfire` job component was implemented in an asynchronous manner, and had a bug that caused a crash while waiting for the response (the underlying `HttpClient` got disposed of while in use). After I fixed that issue, the outbound communication worked as expected...

Answer (score 2):

> There is no special network configuration; the default "bridge" mode
>   is used.

According to your description, it seems you are using a VM and run docker on it.
If you want to access this docker from Internet, we should map docker port to local port, for example:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 my_image service nginx start
```

After we map port 80 to this VM, we should add inbound rules to Azure **network security group**(NSG), we can follow this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-create-nsg-arm-pportal) to add it.

Also we should add port 80 to **OS filewall** inbound rules.

---

**Update**:

Sorry for misunderstand.

Here is my test, I install docker on Azure VM(Ubuntu 16), then create a centos docker, like this:

```
root@jasonvms:~# docker run -i -t centos bash
Unable to find image 'centos:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/centos
d9aaf4d82f24: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:4565fe2dd7f4770e825d4bd9c761a81b26e49cc9e3c9631c58cfc3188be9505a
Status: Downloaded newer image for centos:latest
[root@75f92bf5b499 /]# ping www.google.com
PING www.google.com (172.217.3.100) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from lga34s18-in-f4.1e100.net (172.217.3.100): icmp_seq=1 ttl=47 time=7.93 ms
64 bytes from lga34s18-in-f4.1e100.net (172.217.3.100): icmp_seq=2 ttl=47 time=8.13 ms
64 bytes from lga34s18-in-f4.1e100.net (172.217.3.100): icmp_seq=3 ttl=47 time=8.15 ms
^C
--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 7.939/8.076/8.153/0.121 ms
[root@75f92bf5b499 /]# ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=51 time=1.88 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=51 time=1.89 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=51 time=1.86 ms
c64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=51 time=1.87 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=5 ttl=51 time=1.78 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=6 ttl=51 time=1.87 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 6 received, 0% packet loss, time 5009ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.783/1.861/1.894/0.061 ms
[root@75f92bf5b499 /]#
```

I find it can community with the internet, could you please show me more information about your issue?

Comment: Does that work for you? please let me know if you need more help:)

Comment: @jason-ye-msft Thanks, but your answer is related to inbound connections, which is not the problem here. Otherwise, it would have been very helpful...

Answer (score 0):

if you are using standalone instance then make changes in network_security group of instance and allow outbound rules,
if using ACS follow below link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/dcos-swarm/container-service-enable-public-access